# AJAX comment system, ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am making a comment system for my blog that I am creating and currently I have two problems with it. The form appears under every post. But only works on the top post. The rest of the forms simply don't work.

The another problem I have is that I'm using ajax and the form does add the record to SQL but I still have to refresh my page for it to show. I want it to show automatically straight away after it is added.

tl:dr

**Two problems:**

1. The only form that works is the first one under the first post, the rest simply don't work
2. Ajax doesn't automatically show the comments, need to refresh to seem them

*Code:*

**JQuery**

```html
function post()
{
  var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var mail = document.getElementById("mail").value;
  var post_id = document.getElementById("post_id").value;
  if(comment && name && mail)
  {
    $.ajax
    ({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'php/comment.php',
      data:
      {

      user_comm:comment,
        user_name:name,
      user_mail:mail,
      post_id:post_id,
      },
      success: function (response)
      {
        document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML=response+document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("comment").value="";
      document.getElementById("name").value="";
      document.getElementById("mail").value="";
      }
    });
  }

  return false;
}
```

**Index.php**

```html
<div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
      <?php
           $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY id DESC') or die(mysql_error());

              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $id_post = $row['id'];
                $post_title = $row['post_title'];
                $post_date = $row['date_created'];
                $post_img = $row['post_img'];
                $post_first = $row['post_first'];
                $post_second = $row['post_second'];



               echo " <!-- Blog Post Content Column -->
                    <h1> " . $row['post_title'] . " </h1><p class='lead'>
                    by <a href='#'>Matt</a></p>   <hr>
                     <p><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'>" . $row['date_created'] . "</span></p>
                     <img class='img-responsive' style='width: 900px;height: 300px;' src=" . $row['post_img'] . "> <hr>
                        <p class='lead'>" . $row['post_first'] . "</p>
                        <p>" . $row['post_second'] . "</p> <hr>";


          ?>
                        <!-- Comments Form -->
                    <div class='well'>
                            <h4>Leave a Comment:</h4>
                            <div class="new-com-cnt">
                              <form method='post' onsubmit="return post();">
                                    <input type='hidden' id='post_id'name='post_id' value='<?php  echo $id_post; ?>'>
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                      <input type="text" id="name" name="name-com" value="" placeholder="Your name" />
                                      <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail-com" value="" placeholder="Your e-mail adress" />
                                    <textarea type='text' id='comment' name='comment' class="form-control" rows='3'></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                   <input type="submit" value="Post Comment">
                                  </form>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>

 <?php
               $resultcomments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `comment`  WHERE post_id = '$id_post' ORDER BY `date` DESC") or die(mysql_error());
                        while($affcom = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultcomments)){
                            $name = $affcom['name'];
                            $email = $affcom['mail'];
                            $comment = $affcom['comment'];
                            $date = $affcom['date'];


                            $default = "mm";
                            $size = 35;
                            $grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/".md5(strtolower(trim($email)))."?d=".$default."&s=".$size;

                            ?>

                        <!-- Posted Comments -->
                        <div id='comments'class='media'>

                              <a class='pull-left' href='#'>
                                  <img class='media-object' src=' <?php echo $grav_url; ?>' >
                              </a>
                              <div class='media-body'><?php echo $name; ?>
                                  <h4 class='media-heading'>
                                      <small><?php echo $date; ?></small>
                                  </h4>
                                    <?php echo $comment; ?>
                              </div>
                          </div>

                      <?php
                    }
                  }
                  ?>
            </div>
```

**comment.php**

```html
include_once('../../acp/db/db.php');
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname);
     mysql_select_db($dbname);
     if (!$link) {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }
if(isset($_POST['user_comm']) && isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['user_mail']))
{
  $comment=$_POST['user_comm'];
  $name=$_POST['user_name'];
  $mail=$_POST['user_mail'];
  $post_id=$_POST['post_id'];
  $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment (name,mail,comment,post_id) VALUES ('$name', '$mail', '$comment', '$post_id')");

  $select=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `comment`  WHERE post_id = '$id_post' ORDER BY `date` DESC");

  if($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
  {
      $name=$row['name'];
      $comment=$row['comment'];
    $date=$row['date'];
  ?>
  <div class='media'>
        <a class='pull-left' href='#'>
            <img class='media-object' src=' <?php echo $grav_url; ?>' >
        </a>
        <div class='media-body'><?php echo $name; ?>
            <h4 class='media-heading'>
                <small><?php echo $date; ?></small>
            </h4>
              <?php echo $comment; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
  <?php
  }
exit;
}
?>
```

This is the first time I am playing around with AJAX :) so be easy on me  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this unless you want someone hacking your site. You also need to switch to mysqli_* or PDO as all mysql_* functions are deprecated. Also, you are outputting elements with the same ID multiple times. Finally, you need to use `htmlentities()` or something similar on your output, otherwise users will be able inject code. I REALLY hope this isn't a live site as you are just asking for someone to hack it.

Comment: no, its not going to be live site maybe in the future, I am just learning on it really for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested all your code. It's working now. I commented it overall, so search after "NB" (lat. for "Nota bene") in codes, in order to see were I made relevant changes. I'll describe here some problems with it and I'll also give you some recommendations - if I may. At last I'll insert the three corrected pages.

### Problems:

- One big problem was, that you were using the `$id_post` variable in
  the `SELECT` sql statement (in `comment.php`), which does not exist
  in `comment.php` code.
- Other problem: DOM elements had same ids. The DOM elements inside
  loop-forms must have unique `id` attributes. You must always have
  unique `id` attributes in html elements. Give them the form
  `id="<early-id><post_id>"` for example.
- There were also other problems in more places. I commented overall,
  so you'll have to read my codes.

### Recommendations:

- Use `mysqli_` instead of `mysql_` functions, because `mysql`
  extension were completely removed from PHP >= 7.0.
- Use exception handling, especially when dealing with db access.
- Don't write HTML code from inside php. Alternate php with html if you
  wish, but don't do `echo "<div class=...></div>"` for example. This
  is actually very important if you use an IDE which can format your
  html code. If this code is inside php, you have no chance for this
  beautifying process. therefore you can miss important html-tags
  without knowing it, because your IDE didn't showed you where tags are
  really missing in page.
- In html tags: use same `name` as `id`. Example: `id=mail<?php echo
  $post_id; ?>`, `name=mail<?php echo $post_id; ?>`. Exception: radio
  buttons, checkboxes and all tags which can form a group. Then, each
  tag would have a unique id, but all of them would receive the same
  name.
- Use '' overall and "" inside them. Maintain this "standard", you'll see it's a lot better than the inverse.

---

### Corrected pages:

---

### Index.php:

```
<?php
try {
    $con = mysqli_connect('<host>', '<user>', '<pass>', '<db>');
    if (!$con) {
        throw new Exception('Connect error: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ' - ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>NB: TITLE</title>

            <!-- NB: Added my scripts for testing -->
            <link href="Vendor/Bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/Bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script src="Vendor/jquery-3.1.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="Vendor/Bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <?php
                        $result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY id DESC');
                        if (!$result) {
                            throw new Exception('The query could not be executed!');
                        }

                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            // NB: Unified $post_id name overall (instead of $id_post).
                            $post_id = $row['id'];
                            $post_title = $row['post_title'];
                            $post_date = $row['date_created'];
                            $post_img = $row['post_img'];
                            $post_first = $row['post_first'];
                            $post_second = $row['post_second'];
                            ?>

                            <!-- Blog Post Content Column -->
                            <!-- 
                                NB: Extracted html code from php and added here, where it should be.
                            -->
                            <h1>
                                <?php echo $post_title; ?>
                            </h1>
                            <p class="lead">
                                by <a href="#">Matt</a>
                            </p>
                            <hr/>
                            <p>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time">
                                    <?php echo $post_date; ?>
                                </span>
                            </p>
                            <img class="img-responsive" style="width: 1200px; height: 100px;" src="<?php echo $post_img; ?>">
                            <hr/>
                            <p class="lead">
                                <?php echo $post_first; ?>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <?php echo $post_second; ?>
                            </p>
                            <hr/>

                            <!-- Comments Form -->
                            <div class="well">
                                <h4>Leave a Comment:</h4>
                                <div class="new-com-cnt">
                                    <form method="post" onsubmit="return post('<?php echo $post_id; ?>');">
                                        <!-- 
                                            NB: Deleted hidden input (not needed!) and was missing post_id in "id" attribute! 
                                                So: transfered post_id value to post() function as argument. See js too.
                                        -->
                                        <!-- 
                                            NB: Added post_id to the "id" attributes. See js too. 
                                        -->
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" id="name<?php echo $post_id; ?>" name="name-com" value="" placeholder="Your name" />
                                            <input type="text" id="mail<?php echo $post_id; ?>" name="mail-com" value="" placeholder="Your e-mail adress" />
                                            <textarea type="text" id="comment<?php echo $post_id; ?>" name="comment" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Post Comment">
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <hr>

                            <!-- 
                                NB: Added new "comments" outer-container in order to append 
                                    new comment to it and added post_id value into its "id" attribute.
                                    See the js too.
                            -->
                            <div id="comments<?php echo $post_id; ?>" class="comments-container">
                                <?php
                                $resultComments = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM `comment`  WHERE post_id = ' . $post_id . ' ORDER BY `date` DESC');
                                if (!$resultComments) {
                                    throw new Exception('The query could not be executed!');
                                }

                                while ($affcom = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultComments)) {
                                    $name = $affcom['name'];
                                    $email = $affcom['mail'];
                                    $comment = $affcom['comment'];
                                    $date = $affcom['date'];

                                    $default = "mm";
                                    $size = 35;
                                    $grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5(strtolower(trim($email))) . "?d=" . $default . "&s=" . $size;
                                    ?>

                                    <!-- Posted Comments -->
                                    <!-- 
                                        NB: deleted id attribute "comments", because I added an outer
                                        container to hold the insert results, e.g. the div 
                                        with the class "comments-container".
                                    -->
                                    <div class="media">
                                        <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                                            <img class="media-object" src="<?php echo $grav_url; ?>" >
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="media-body">
                                            <?php echo $name; ?>
                                            <h4 class="media-heading">
                                                <small><?php echo $date; ?></small>
                                            </h4>
                                            <?php echo $comment; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    $closed = mysqli_close($con);
    if (!$closed) {
        throw new Exception('The database connection can not be closed!');
    }
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    // NB: Here you should just DISPLAY the error message.
    echo $exception->getMessage();

    // NB: And here you should LOG your whole $exception object.
    // NB: Never show the whole object to the user!
    // echo '<pre>' . print_r($exception, true) . '</pre>';

    exit();
}
?>
```

---

### comment.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>NB: TITLE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        try {
            $con = mysqli_connect('<host>', '<user>', '<pass>', '<db>');
            if (!$con) {
                throw new Exception('Connect error: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ' - ' . mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            if (isset($_POST['user_comm']) && isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['user_mail'])) {
                $comment = $_POST['user_comm'];
                $name = $_POST['user_name'];
                $mail = $_POST['user_mail'];
                $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

                // NB: NEW. CHANGE THIS TO YOUR wished DATE FORMAT.
                // Use UNIX timestamps for dates, so that you make good date calculations.
                $date = date("Y-m-d");

                // NB: INSERT DATE IN DB TOO, so that you can select by date desc down under.
                $insert = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO comment (name,mail,comment,post_id, date) VALUES ('$name', '$mail', '$comment', '$post_id', '$date')");
                if (!$insert) {
                    throw new Exception('The query could not be executed!');
                }

                // NB: Replaced $id_post with $post_id.
                $select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `comment`  WHERE post_id = '$post_id' ORDER BY `date` DESC");
                if (!$select) {
                    throw new Exception('The query could not be executed!');
                }

                if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
                    $name = $row['name'];
                    // NB: Added email, because it wasn't provided.
                    $email = $row['mail'];
                    $comment = $row['comment'];
                    $date = $row['date'];

                    // NB: It wasn't provided, so I added the same value as in index.php.
                    $default = "mm";
                    $size = 35;
                    $grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5(strtolower(trim($email))) . "?d=" . $default . "&s=" . $size;
                    ?>
                    <div class="media">
                        <a class='pull-left' href='#'>
                            <!-- 
                                NB: Where is your $grav_url value?! I added one of mine for testing.
                            -->
                            <img class='media-object' src=' <?php echo $grav_url; ?>' >
                        </a>
                        <div class='media-body'>
                            <?php echo $name; ?>
                            <h4 class='media-heading'>
                                <small><?php echo $date; ?></small>
                            </h4>
                            <?php echo $comment; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }

                // NB: Don't use exit(). Let the code flow further, because 
                // you maybe want to close the db connection!
                // exit();
            }

            $closed = mysqli_close($con);
            if (!$closed) {
                throw new Exception('The database connection can not be closed!');
            }
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            // NB: Here you should just DISPLAY the error message.
            echo $exception->getMessage();

            // NB: And here you should LOG your whole $exception object.
            // NB: Never show the whole object to the user!
            // echo '<pre>' . print_r($exception, true) . '</pre>';

            exit();
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

### Javascript file:

```
// NB: Added post_id as parameter. See form too.
function post(post_id) {
    // NB: Added post_id value to the "id" attributes. See form too.
    var comment = document.getElementById("comment" + post_id).value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name" + post_id).value;
    var mail = document.getElementById("mail" + post_id).value;

    if (comment && name && mail) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'php/comment.php',
            data: {
                user_comm: comment,
                user_name: name,
                user_mail: mail,
                post_id: post_id
            },
            success: function (response) {
                // NB: Comments-post_id is now an outer container. See form.
                // NB: Added post_id value to the "id" attributes. See form too.
                document.getElementById("comments" + post_id).innerHTML = response + document.getElementById("comments" + post_id).innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("comment" + post_id).value = "";
                document.getElementById("name" + post_id).value = "";
                document.getElementById("mail" + post_id).value = "";
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
}


// ******************************************************************************
// NB: Recommendation:
// ******************************************************************************
// Use jquery and ajax instead of vanilla javascript. It's no problem anymore ;-)
// Use done, fail, always instead of success, error, ....
// ******************************************************************************
//function post(post_id) {
//    var comment = $('#comment' + post_id);
//    var name = $('#name' + post_id);
//    var mail = $('#mail' + post_id);
//
//    if (comment && name && mail) {
//        var ajax = $.ajax({
//            method: 'POST',
//            dataType: 'html',
//            url: 'php/comment.php',
//            data: {
//                user_comm: comment.val(),
//                user_name: name.val(),
//                user_mail: mail.val(),
//                post_id: post_id
//            }
//        });
//        ajax.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
//            var comments = $("#comments" + post_id);
//            
//            // NB: I'm not sure, not tested, too tired :-) Please recherche.
//            comments.html(data + comments.html());
//            
//            comment.val('');
//            name.val('');
//            mail.val('');
//        });
//        ajax.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
//            // Show error in a customized messages div, for example.
//            $('#flashMessage').val(textStatus + '<br />' + errorThrown);
//        });
//        ajax.always(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
//            //...
//        });
//    }
//
//    return false;
//}
// ******************************************************************************
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) I will apply all the changes and try to stick to all the tips given to me on this post, I have only been doing web dev for around a year and only now started taking this seriously so I'm learning, thanks for the tips!

Comment: @Mattboro You are welcome! :-) I would also recommend you to use OOP and  MVC pattern (Model-View-Controller). Try to develop your own PHP MVC. You will then **automatically** learn everything, you'll have a very good practice and you'll be a very good OOP web developer. And use PDO instead mysqli. PDO is object oriented, so it's a good start. If you need other tips, feel free to ask anytime. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Your parent loop is generating several comments form and they all have the same id. Ids are supposed to be unique for the whole document. refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). Perhaps this is causing other comment forms not to work except the first one.

Your second problem is not an issue. It is general behavior of how server works. When you are using ajax, it is sending data to the server which stores it in the database. Server's job is done. It cannot send the data back to the page and update the page content without refreshing the page. You can initiate another ajax call after posting to server in order to refresh the content of the page.

And though it is not related to the question. Try to be consistent with your use of single quotes and double quotes. You shouldn't randomly choose them. Decide on one and use them consistently. And yes do try to learn PDO or mysqli. I will suggest PDO.